# htaccess rewrite current correct url to appear as something else, and also if other url entered, redirect to this one

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hey so I'm trying to get my htaccess file to do 2 things:

1) if user enters `http://dstealth.com/i` or `http://dstealth.com/i/some/other/address` I want htaccess file to use `http://dstealth.com/z_index/` or `http://dstealth.com/z_index/some/other/address`

2) I also want the htaccess file to redirect the user if they use the old address. eg if user types `http://dstealth.com/z_index` or `http://dstealth.com/z_index/some/other/address` I want the URL to appear as `http://dstealth.com/i/some/other/address`

Basically at all times replace `z_index` with `i` even though the directory `i` does not exist and `z_index` is still the directory being used.

I've tried a bunch of stuff and it seems not to be working as it keep redirecting me to my 404 page.

My .htaccess file:

```
ServerSignature Off 
ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error_pages/500.php
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine - only needed once
Options -MultiViews

# Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

# Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Rewrite www.dstealth.com as dstealth.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dstealth\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dstealth.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

# Rewrite /z_index/ as /i/
RewriteRule ^z_index/([^/.]+)$ /i/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^i/([^/.]+)$ /z_index/$1 [NC,L]
```

results:

- `http://dstealth.com/z_index/` still appears exactly the same and doesnt change to `http://dstealth.com/i/`
- `http://dstealth.com/i/` takes me to my 404 page :(

Comment: the rewrite works the other way round: The User types in `dstealth/i` and .htaccess rewrites to `dstealth/z_index`. htaccess cannot rewrite what the user has in his address bar, nor the links he is clicking. But it can rewrite what it gets as a request and then send the updated version to the web-server.

Comment: okay that being taken into consideration i've managed for it to rewrite dstealth/i to dstealth/z_index BUT i still get sent to 404 if i try any sub directories like dstealth/i/something/else. This is my htaccess `RewriteRule ^i$ /z_index/?&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^i/([^/.]+)$ /z_index/$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got what I want with the following code. Please let me know if it has any errors or inefficiencies:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/z_index [NC]
RewriteRule ^z_index/([^.]+)\.php$ /i/$1\.php [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/z_index [NC]
RewriteRule ^z_index/([^.]+)$ /i/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/z_index [NC]
RewriteRule ^z_index/?$ /i/ [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^i/([^.]+)\.php$ /z_index/$1\.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^i/$ /z_index/?&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```